# Selenium driver - Handling Browser windows opened through JavaScript

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver

Here's our routine driver instantiation code

```
WebDriver driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://internal.com");
```

Let's say that the above opens an instance (window) of IE - Window 1. In this case, we have some JS on internal.com's index.html that opens a new window, say Window 2. The problem is that when we quit the driver, we can easily close Window 1 but we seem to have no control over Window 2.

```
driver.quit();
```

Are there any clean ways to close Window 2 and any other derivative browser windows at the end of every test case?

Comment: I would have thought that quitting the driver would have closed all windows. Have you tried looping through all window handles and closing each one before quitting?

Comment: Try to find that specific window using your code than activate it and close it using Close() method. than after try to use driver.quit(); to close other window. Ref: https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5552/what-is-close-and-quit-commands-in-selenium-webdriver